# Spring security oAuth2 - Implicit token with forms authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, forms-authentication, spring-security-oauth2

I'm new to spring security in general, and I have been experimenting with spring security oAuth2. I can use the following to get a token from the authorize endpoint implicitly, if I enable httpBasic in the configuration and use a basic authentication header:

http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize?client_id=portal&client_secret=portalSecret&response_type=token&redirect_uri=saveCode

I'm trying to do the same with forms authentication instead of basic. But when I send the credentials as form data, I always get redirected to the login form.

Here's my configuration:

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class PortalWebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        PasswordEncoder fastPasswordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
            authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(fastPasswordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Bean
        AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
            return new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
//When this is enabled, basic authentication works 
                       //.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()

                    .formLogin().permitAll().and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/saveCode").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").fullyAuthenticated().antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()
                    .and().exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
        }
    }
```

And the oAuth2 configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource";
    private static final int TOKEN_LIVE_SECONDS = 120;
    private static final String PORTAL_CLIENT_NAME = "portal";
    private static final String PORTAL_CLIENT_SECRET = "portalSecret";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("tokenServices")
        private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/saveCode").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers("/secure/**").fullyAuthenticated().and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

        @Configuration
        @EnableAuthorizationServer
        protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired
            @Qualifier("tokenServices")
            private AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices;

            @Autowired
            private TokenStore tokenStore;

            @Autowired
            private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

            @Autowired
            private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

            @Override
            public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                clients.inMemory().withClient(PORTAL_CLIENT_NAME).secret(PORTAL_CLIENT_SECRET).scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "authorization_code", "refresh-token").authorities('Admin_Role')
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).accessTokenValiditySeconds(TOKEN_LIVE_SECONDS).autoApprove(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
                security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to be able to get the token without passing by the login form itself (like when calling a service). Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Thanks in advance.